Radare2 debug mode dc not working properly
I have a C program that simply prints "Hello, world!", I started the program using r2 -d test.exe. As soon as I did that, r2 says "INFO: Spawned new process with pid...". and if I run dc, it open up another cmd, quickly print hello word and exist. I want to work in the same terminal.
radare2 debug mode starting new cmd instead of working in the same one
